# how to calculate sum of row in crystal report using sql query, and do not display if the sum equals to 0.00

Tags: mysql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have the following crystal report, I want to calculate the sum of each row of specific columns:

1. Opening Quantity
2. Purchase Quantity

   3. Issue Quantity

if sum of the above 3 columns is equal to 0.00, then do not print that record.

Please look out at the screenshot of generated report:[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am to guess here  that the fields are placed in the `DETAIL` section , if then you can use the suppress formula(Section Expert-->Detail Section-->Suppress formula)
and try something like this

```
{Opening Quantity field} + {Purchase Quantity field} + {Issue Quantity field} = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can give some idea to you

1) you have to create a formula to sum up the opening quantity, purchase quantity and Issue quantity by using Running Total Field.

Let say your field name for opening quantity inside the TableA is 'opening quantity'.
Thus, choose Table A, inside the Running Total Field and find the 'opening quantity'.
Then, choose 'SUM' as Type of Summary.

Do the same for another two fields.

At last, you will have 3 different running total field formula.

2) combine together these 3 formula inside one new formula.
Your final formula should look like this.

Let say you name it as Formula 4

if {@Formula1}+{@Formula2}+{@Formula3}<>0 then {@formula1}+{@formula2}+{@formula3}

then you drag this formula to any space in the report that you want the total to appear.

3) After drag it, right click on the formula and press 'Format Object'
Check the suppress box and write this inside the blue cross tab beside the suppress checkbox
{@Formula4}=0